# C code preprocessing in Perl

Tags: c, perl, preprocessor

I work on the `C` code parser in `Perl`.

At the moment I need to pre-process the code.
Implementation of the pre-processing seems to be a lot of work, so I am looking for a script or library that will allow to pre-process the file.

I found the following possibilities:

1. [Text::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/~shevek/Text-CPP/CPP.pm)
2. [Filter::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/Filter-1.49/lib/Filter/cpp.pm)

Both of these require `cpp` which I don't have on my Windows machine. Are there any other options?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filter%3A%3Acpp says `This source filter pipes the current source file through the C pre-processor (cpp) if it is available.`

Comment: `Text::CPP` says it requires `A working C compiler`.

Comment: @devnull that's a problem...

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Who would preprocess if not a compiler?

Comment: @devnull it is a proprietary compiler, that does not seem to have `-save-temps`...

Comment: @Alex most of the preprocessing rules are really simple text replacement or omissions.  You can write your own pretty simply

Comment: @Nirk Unfortunately I have only about 2 months of perl experience, so yes, I can do that but it will take about a half of my current experience.

Comment: It's hard to imagine of a compiler that doesn't show preprocessed code.  Check out, there must be an option.

Comment: @devnull In gcc and clang, the -E option just does preprocessing

Comment: @Alex - preprocessing is typically generic, so you can plug in gcc instead of your proprietary compiler for that.

Comment: @DVK, thanks, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I found a Java based C preprocessor: https://github.com/shevek/jcpp. I think you would have to let it produce new source files from your originals though for it to be of any use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your needs, but you are right that implementing this yourself is probably a poor choice.  I was recently looking for alternative C preprocessors as well.

The [Text::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/~shevek/Text-CPP/) module should only require a compiler to compile itself.  If you can find a precompiled version, it should work for you.

The [JCPP Java C Preprocessor](http://www.anarres.org/projects/jcpp/) by the same author could probably be made to work.  You'd likely have to process externally and then load the result.

[Filepp](http://www.cabaret.demon.co.uk/filepp/) is an older Perl program that claims CPP compatability.  There is a precompiled Windows binary to download.

There is a brand new [Lua C-Preprocessor LCPP](http://lcpp.schmoock.net/) that might be something you could work with.  Probably best as a standalone, but you might be able to use [Inline::Lua](http://search.cpan.org/~rhoelz/Inline-Lua-0.05/lib/Inline/Lua.pm).

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Preprocessor.html) comes with its own preprocessor implementation.  I presume this would be available for Windows.

What else?  The [Boost Wave Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/wave/) might work well and is available for Windows. 
The MSVC Compiler can [preprocess to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx).

Still, the easiest and best long term solution may be to just install CPP.  It comes as part of GCC, which you can get from [Cygwin](http://sourceware.org/cygwin/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).